# Unable to solve incompatible with attribute error in android

Tags: android, attrs.xml

I have a following error andI have no clue why this is happening.All I did was add the flag
called "mon" and tried to add it to the custom view in the xml. flags other than "mon" works
well. What is the meaning of this error? I would love to  hear from you.

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  samp/app/src/main/res/layout/layout_mon.xml:2: error: 'mon' is incompatible with attribute mon_type (attr) flags [sol=1, dan=4, tin=2] [weak].
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: /Users/me/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/0c6f710daca8a09e3/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
        /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar\
        --manifest\
      /Users/me/Documents/samp/app/build/intermediates/instant_run_merged_manifests/_stagingDebug/process_stagingDebugManifest/instant-run/AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        /Users/me/Documents/samp/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/_stagingDebug/process_stagingDebugResources/out/resources-_stagingDebug.ap_\
        -R\
        @/Users/me/Documents/samp/app/build/intermediates/incremental/process_stagingDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-_stagingDebug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        /Users/me/Documents/samp/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/_stagingDebug/process_stagingDebugResources/r\
        --custom-package\
        jp.aeonretail.aeon.kidsrepublic\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        xxhdpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        /Users/me/Documents/samp/app/build/intermediates/symbols/_st/debug/R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
```

//inside the attrs

```
<declare-styleable name="MonView">
    <attr name="mon_type">
        <flag name="sol" value="0x01"/>
        <flag name="dan" value="0x02"/>
        <flag name="tin" value="0x04"/>
        <flag name="mon" value="0x06"/>
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

//view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<example.MonView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mon_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:mon_type="mon"
</example.MonView>
```

Comment: you can only use values which is defined in attr flag.

Comment: In your code you use `month`, not `mon`

Answer (score 2):

You declared the name of property but the type of input is not specified
change your attrs to

```
<declare-styleable name="MonView">
<attr name="mon_type" format="flags">
    <flag name="sol" value="0x01"/>
    <flag name="dan" value="0x02"/>
    <flag name="tin" value="0x04"/>
    <flag name="mon" value="0x06"/>
</attr></declare-styleable>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If it worked before, then that's not the root of the problem. It seems that it's failing on the runtime when received attributes are mapped to some type/logic in the custom view that uses these attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you have a custom view of some kind that uses this attributes, something like MonView. Could you please provide the code of this View as well? It should be either a java or kotlin class. 
It seems that when you get your attributes on the runtime in your view that utilises them, it will try to map received attribute value to some preset array position or enum type inside you custom view type. Since you've only added the new attribute to the xml, but haven't updated the array (or enum, or just some logic with a switch/case, however it's implemented) you get this error. Hope, this will help. I'll be able to tell you more if there is a right code snippet. Cheers.